# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' while reading firebasedatabase v9+

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have two files `main.dart` and a class `history.dart`
the `main.dart` takes a `DataSnapShot` from firebase and the `history.dart` will sort out the Map.

the `main.dart`

```
late DatabaseReference rideRequestRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Ride Requests");
static void obtainTripRequestsHistoryData(context) async {
    var keys = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).tripHistoryKeys;

    for (String key in keys) {
      rideRequestRef.child(key);

      DatabaseEvent event = await rideRequestRef.once();

      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        DatabaseEvent event =
            await rideRequestRef.child(key).child('rider_name').once();

        String name = event.snapshot.value.toString();

        if (name == userCurrentInfo.name) {
          var history = History.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
          Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
              .updateTripHistoryData(history);
        }
        //});
      }
      //});
    }
  }
```

the `History.dart`

```
class History {
  String? paymentMethod;
  String? createdAt;
  String? status;
  int? fares;
  String? dropOff;
  String? pickup;

  History(
      {this.paymentMethod,
      this.createdAt,
      this.status,
      this.fares,
      this.dropOff,
      this.pickup});

  History.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    dynamic data = dataSnapshot.value;

    paymentMethod = data["payment_method"];
    createdAt = data["created_at"];
    status = data["status"];
    fares = data["fares"];
    dropOff = data["dropoff_address"];
    pickup = data["pickup_address"];
  }
}
```

I get an error on `paymentMethod = data["payment_method"];`and the rest.

the error

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Next, I changed to

```
  History.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = dataSnapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

    final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
        (dataSnapshot).value as Map);

    paymentMethod = data["payment_method"];
    createdAt = data["created_at"];
    status = data["status"];
    fares = data["fares"];
    dropOff = data["dropoff_address"];
    pickup = data["pickup_address"];
  }
}
```

The error

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

I have checked this forum throughout but most are unanswered. The ones that supposedly worked don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `event` twice:

```
DatabaseEvent event = await rideRequestRef.once(); // 

if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
  DatabaseEvent event = // 
      await rideRequestRef.child(key).child('rider_name').once();
```

So the `event` that you pass to the `` function is a snapshot of just the `rider_name`, which seems to be a string value.

To fix this and improve the code, you don't even need that second `once` call, as the value of `rider_name` is already present in the initial snapshot:

```
DatabaseEvent event = await rideRequestRef.once();

if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
  String name = event.snapshot.child(key).child('rider_name').value.toString();
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you,  I have updated my working code in V8, when I was just using `DataSnapShot` .I believe I am not able to extract single data event  from `DatabaseEvent `

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you pass the expected data type for data coming from a server like this

```
...
paymentMethod = data["payment_method"] as String;
createdAt = data["created_at"] as String;
status = data["status"] as String;
fares = data["fares"] as int;
dropOff = data["dropoff_address"] as String;
pickup = data["pickup_address"] as String;
...
```

Also can you show the kind of data you're receiving from firebase?

Comment: code updated, I have already tried that but it doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
static void obtainTripRequestsHistoryData(context) async {
    var keys = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).tripHistoryKeys;
    DatabaseEvent event = await rideRequestRef.once();

// Print the data of the snapshot
    print(event.snapshot.value);
    for (String key in keys) {
      rideRequestRef.child(key).once().then((event) {
        if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
          rideRequestRef
              .child(key)
              .child("rider_name")
              .once()
              .then((eventvalue) {
            print("obtainTrip  " + eventvalue.snapshot.value.toString());
            String name = eventvalue.snapshot.value.toString();
            if (name == userCurrentInfo.name) {
              var history = History.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
              Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                  .updateTripHistoryData(history);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
```